# Override a css style

Tags: html, css

So I have a big trouble understanding how to override a css rule inhered, with my css rules define in some class for example

first i have this html

```
<a class="formatText" style="font-weight:bold">Accesorios 4x4</a>
```

And I defined a class formatText like this

```
.formatText{
font-size:14px;
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
}
```

Never the less, because i'm using jquery-ui in some point the rule that match with the element is this

```
.ui-widget-content a {
     color: black;
}
```

How can fixed this without defined a css selector by ID.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.ui-widget-content a.formatText{
   font-size:14px;
   font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: #FFF;
}
```

it's a part of basic specificity rules.. you can read further in [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)

and avoid `!important` as possible as you can because it will give us headache in the future trust me. make `!important` as your latest arsenal when there's no hope..but as long as specificity still able to help, use it.

Answer (score 1):

You must define your style rule to be more specific than the `.ui-widget-content a` style rule.  This could be done as follows:

```
.ui-widget-content a.formatText {
    ...
    color: #FFF;
}
```

If this is not feasible, you can also mark the setting as important:

```
color: #FFF !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-widget-content a.formatText {
     color: #FFF;
}
```

done

Answer (score 0):

try adding a span around the text inside the a href like this

```
<a style="font-weight:bold"><span class="formatText">Accesorios 4x4</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override a CSS style introduced later in your document with an earlier one, use the `!important` declaration.

e.g:

```
.formatText{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: An aside: when I was first learning CSS, I would get confused by `!important` since the `!`, interpreted as a logical operator, made it appear that any style with this declaration was **NOT** important and would be overridden by styles without the declaration. Cool story, I know. Did anyone else struggle with this?